# Can Locate command output only genuine files (not directories)

Tags: command-line, locate, updatedb

I am building a home made catalog/indexer of my PDF/DJVU/EPUB/LIT/unspecified files. I need only index the file names. Indexing contents are not needed as I always keep descriptive file names. The locate command does a good job and outputs the results (after I build the index with updatedb).

However I would like to see only genuine files, not directories. Can I manipulate locate into such a behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any `locate` implementation that checks file types.

You can use Bash to filter the `locate` output:

```
while read -r -d $'\0' f
do
    [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f"
done < <(locate -0 something)
```

Or you can use `find` with the `-type f` option:

```
find / -name something -type f
```